# Wrong windows name in GRUB bootloader

Tags: bootloader

I have a duel boot pc which runs Linux and Windows 7. I not sure if this is Windows or Linux fault but the GRUB (linux bootloader) give me option to either boot to Linux or to WIndows 8 which isn't right. However if I select Windows 8 it will boot to Windows 7 correctly.

I did used to have windows 8 on my pc last year as a duel boot to Windows 7 (no linux was on the pc) but I have wiped it but it seems that there is still bit of windows 8 bootloader code lying somewhere around. 
I have tried bootrec many times but it doesn't change the name. I did try wipe GRUB again and install it but it still saying Windows 8.

Please could anyone help? :)
Thanks

Comment: If you download Grub Editor from the Software Centre you can then edit the text to reflect the correct OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways you can accomplish that:

Use Grub Customizer.   Its a GUI that allows you control over GRUB2 settings and menuentries.  To install Grub Customizer, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Or you can do it manually by editing the `grub.cf`g file, located at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.