# How to remove Windows entry from Boot

Tags: 13.04, windows-7

My system was a dual boot system

Ubuntu and Windows.

Now that I have removed Windows but the thing is thing I just formated the drive from within the Ubuntu. But during boot the Windows entry is still appearing during Boot.

How to remove the Windows Entry from Boot Grub.

Comment: Try Grub Customizer.  Take a look at this answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/319880/wrong-windows-name-in-grub-bootloader/319906#319906).

Comment: Ok, I will do it and let you all know

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following to update the boot menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```