# How to change the name of os in grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I bought a laptop with DOS and installed Windows in it and then I installed Ubuntu. So, now I am using both Ububtu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 with Grub2 as bootloader.

But in the bootloader menu "Windows 10" is displayed as "Free DOS"

How can I change "Free DOS" to "Windows 10".

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Editing OS names in /etc/default/grub - where is the OS name read from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822757/editing-os-names-in-etc-default-grub-where-is-the-os-name-read-from) since that post only says how the command `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian` is used and where does it takes the names from.

My question is different since I want to change the name of Windows OS which has nothing to do with the above command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing OS names in /etc/default/grub - where is the OS name read from?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/822757/editing-os-names-in-etc-default-grub-where-is-the-os-name-read-from) A duplicate indeed. You may edit your question, refer to the suggestions you've tried and the results, point out exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong windows name in GRUB bootloader](http://askubuntu.com/questions/319880/wrong-windows-name-in-grub-bootloader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (root permissions needed).

Search for "Free DOS" and replace it with "Windows 10" save and reboot (this is a temporary fix running `update-grub` the next time may bring back the problem)

For a permanent fix you may want to open a terminal and run `os-prober` then `update-grub` and reboot to see if the issue is resolved

Comment: You should never use `sudo`with `gedit`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications

Comment: This change will get wiped out the next time `update-grub` is run.

Comment: @Organic Marble yes you have a point maybe he  should run "os-prober" then "update-grub" that may also work

Comment: @Josephson47 what about editing your answer accordingly?